# Adding a class to li element dynamically using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am trying to add a class 'block' to certain li elements using jquery but the class is not getting added.
The program is to show the time slots. if the certain time is blocked then it should be disabled.
the program to create the time slots is here

```
    public function __construct(){
        $this->_meta['instance']='time';
        $this->_meta['class']='time';
    }

    private function _selectbox($start,$end,$currentTime=false,$id=false,$name=false,$class=false){

        $fromtime=$start;
        $totime= $fromtime + "1";
        $select = '<ul class="'.$class.'">';
        for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i++){
            while($fromtime<$end){
            $li='<li id="li-'.$fromtime.':00-'.$totime.':00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-'.$fromtime.':00-'.$totime.':00" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$fromtime.':00-'.$totime.':00"/>'.$fromtime.':00-'.$totime.':00</li>';
            $select.=$li;
            $fromtime=$fromtime + "1";
            $totime=$totime + "1";

            }
        }

        return $select;
    } 
        public function show($meta=array()){        
        $this->_meta=array_merge($this->_meta,$meta);   
        return $this->_hour();
    }
```

here i'm getting the blocked time slots and passing those variables to views.

```
    $date = $_SESSION['date'];
    $blocks = $block->getBlocksPerDay(date('d',strtotime($date)),
                                      date('m',strtotime($date)),
                                      date('Y',strtotime($date)));

    $this->setData('blocks',$blocks);
    $this->setData('date',$date);


         public function getBlocksPerDay($day,$month,$year){
    $connection = db::factory('mysql');

    $sql = 'select *  from blocks WHERE date LIKE "'.$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.'%"';

    return $connection->getArray($sql);
}
```

Here is the view in which i'm sending the blocks as $blocks in input type hidden and also showing the time slots

```
          <?php echo $time->show(array('instance'=>'from'));?>

            <?php 
if(sizeof($blocks)>0){
    foreach($blocks as $block){
        $time_from=explode(":",$block['time_from']);
        $time_from_part1=$time_from[0];
        $time_from_part2=$time_from[1];
        $time_to=explode(":",$block['time_to']);
        $time_to_part1=$time_to['0'];
        $time_to_part2=$time_to['1'];
        //echo $time_from_part1':'$time_from_part2'-'$time_to_part1':'$time_to_part2;
        echo '<input type="hidden" class="blocks" disabled="disabled" value="'.$time_from_part1.':'.$time_from_part2.'-'.$time_to_part1.':'.$time_to_part2.'"/>';
    }
}
?>
```

And Lastly here is the Jquery to add the class to li element to block the particular li element

```
           $(document).ready(function() {   
             function setBlocks(){ 
    var blocks = $('.blocks');
    $.each(blocks,function(index,value){
        $('#li-'+$(value).val()).addClass('block');
        //$('#li-'+$(value).val()).find('input').remove();
    });
}
setBlocks();
        });
```

Here is the HTML Output Generated

```
                <ul class="time"><li id="li-10:00-11:00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-10:00-11:00" name="from-time-hour" value="10:00-11:00"/>10:00-11:00</li><li id="li-11:00-12:00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-11:00-12:00" name="from-time-hour" value="11:00-12:00"/>11:00-12:00</li><li id="li-12:00-13:00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-12:00-13:00" name="from-time-hour" value="12:00-13:00"/>12:00-13:00</li><li id="li-13:00-14:00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-13:00-14:00" name="from-time-hour" value="13:00-14:00"/>13:00-14:00</li><li id="li-14:00-15:00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-14:00-15:00" name="from-time-hour" value="14:00-15:00"/>14:00-15:00</li><li id="li-15:00-16:00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-15:00-16:00" name="from-time-hour" value="15:00-16:00"/>15:00-16:00</li><li id="li-16:00-17:00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-16:00-17:00" name="from-time-hour" value="16:00-17:00"/>16:00-17:00</li><li id="li-17:00-18:00" class="" style="width:24%;"><input type="radio"  id="radio-17:00-18:00" name="from-time-hour" value="17:00-18:00"/>17:00-18:00</li>

              <input type="hidden" class="blocks" disabled="disabled" value="10:00-11:00"/>
```

Is there any fix???

Comment: too much code up there. Try to identify where the problem is and just post the useful code.

Comment: I think it's better if you give us the html output from php instead. Do you get any output if you do console.log( $('#li-'+this.value) ); inside the loop?

Comment: I didnt tried this one

Comment: If your "setBlocks" function is placed in the `<head>` and not in a "ready" or "load" handler, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id's are invalid, for instance you have `li-10:00-11:00`, `:` (semicolons) cant be used for id's, change the way you generate your id's

since you need the times put them in the data-* attributes of the tag, and use jQuery's [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) function to retrieve it.

**Generate HTML Like:**

```
<li id="someUniqueId" data-time="10:00-11:00" class="" style="width:24%;">
```

**In Javascript**

```
var time = jQuery("#someUniqueId").data("time");
//Now "time" will contain "10:00-11:00"
console.log(time);
//console.log will display time in console
```

Comment: Sorry dude the setBlocks Function is called when DOM is ready, i didnt added the code up there but i edited now

Comment: your id's are also invalid, they contain `:`

Comment: I didnt get u... Where it is invalid? and y??

Comment: they contain `:` (semicolons) as you use times as part of the id you cannot have `:` in the ids

Comment: Yes if i wont keep : then my code wont store the time as i wanted

Comment: then put the time in a data-* attribute, like `data-time="11:00-12:00"`, and retrieve using the `.data` jquery function on the element.

Comment: can u please elaborate ur answer, im little confused by wat u told

Comment: how to add class using jquery buddy... how to retrieve the data-time for each li elements

Comment: as i said your id's for the elements are invalid, jQuery can not select an element if the id you are selecting it by is invalid, fix the ids and your code will work properly for adding the class. 

As for retrieving the time as i showed just simply use the `.data` function on the element to get the time. to get all the li elements you can do something like jQuery(".time li"), and then use the `.each` function to loop over the elements

Comment: i'll try ur idea once and will come back with answer... thanks